# Ignoring some modkey bindings in awesome

Tags: awesome-wm

I changed my awesome modkey to "Control". But I want Control-t to open a new tab in my web browser. Is it possible to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out. I simply commented out the

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.ontop = not c.ontop            end),
```

line like this

```
--awful.key({ modkey,           }, "t",      function (c) c.ontop = not c.ontop            end),
```